# Given $p$ odd prime and $G=S_p$ and $P\leq G$ $p$-Sylow and $H=N_G(P)$ find $|H|$ and prove if $p=5$ then $H \cong C_4 \ltimes C_5 $

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

Given $p$ odd prime and $G=S_p$ and $P\leq G$ $p$-Sylow and $H=N_G(P)$ find $|H|$ and prove if $p=5$ then $H \cong C_4 \ltimes C_5 $.

For the first part we know that if we set $n_p$ the number of Sylow groups in $G$ then $n_p=1(p)$ and $n_p\mid (p-1)!$ so $n_p\in\{1,(p-2)!\}$ if $n_p=1$ then $P$ is normal and $H$ is all $G$ and otherwise we can use the stabilizer orbit thm. and get $|H|=p(p-1)$ not sure how to should I procced and say that $n_p\neq1$ and not sure if the calculations are right.
any help please

Comment: Since $p$ is odd, $P \leq A_p$ and $A_p$ is simple if $p \geq 5$.  Therefore, some element of $A_p$ must fall outside $N_G(P)$ and $H \neq G$. If $p=3$, then $[S_3:P]=2$ and $P$ is normal in $S_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

1. $P$ is a cyclic group. Let $P=\operatorname{gr}(\sigma)$.
2. For every $k$, $0<k<p$ there exists $\alpha\in S_p$ such that
   $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}=\sigma^k$.
3. If $\alpha,\beta\in S_p$ and $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}=\beta\sigma\beta^{-1}$, then
   $\alpha P=\beta P$.
4. It follows that $|H/P|=p-1$. In fact $H/P\cong\mathbb{Z}_p^*$.